# kotlin - rewrite a class in such a way that it doesn't violate Liskov substitution

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, interface, uml, solid-principles

I have an UML diagram and I need to rewrite ClassE and in the same time I need to respect Liskov substitution principle. I read about this principle but I got stuck at the ClassE.

I'm thinking to rewrite ClassE such that it implements those 3 interfaces A,B,C and in the Component I would have 3 objects of type A,B and C. Is my approach correct? In other words, I would remove interface D.

Another approach I'm thinking is to split ClassE in 3 classes, each of these classes to implement A,B,C.
Can you give me some hints? I use Kotlin.
[image]

Comment: Can you show some code please?

Comment: Is this a homework question about UML diagrams or are you trying to solve a programming problem? If it is not the latter, it is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: One reason this might fail is if you have code that uses interface D as a type. Kotlin doesn't have intersection types, so there's no other way to say ‘a type that implements interface A _and_ interface B _and_ interface C’ if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing suggest that `classE` may have any issue with Liskov’s substituion principle as it is.

In fact LSP is about contracts that are guaranteed to be fulfilled (pre-conditions, post-conditions, invariants and history).

In this design, `D` could offer a contract that is more than just the contracts of A,B and C taken separately. Therefore removing D would not solve any LSP issue.

***Remark:** adding code to your question would not help, unless it would  contain explicit assertions of preconditions, postconditions and invariants. Adding the code and the contract it is supposed to fulfill would help more*